# How to import standard DOM element props in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, tsx

I am creating React components in TypeScript and type hinting the props like such:

```
export interface ExampleProps {
  someProp: string,
  anotherProp: React.ReactNode
}

export default function Example({
  someProp, 
  ...props
}: ExampleProps) {
  return (
    <div {...props}>...</div>
  );
}
```

I would like to also pass on standard React/HTML props like `className`, `children`, `style`, `id`, `title`, `lang`, etc... without having to explicitly write out all of them. So I can do something like:

```
<Example className="some-class" someProp="value" anotherProp={<div></div>}>Content</Example>
```

I would have thought that it should be possible to extend an interface for this like:

```
export interface ExampleProps extends PropsWithChildren {
  someProp: string,
  anotherProp: React.ReactNode
}
```

But this complains: `Generic type 'PropsWithChildren' requires 1 type argument(s)`

```
export interface ExampleProps extends PropsWithChildren<typeof Example> {
  someProp: string,
  anotherProp: React.ReactNode
}
```

But this complains, `Type { children: string; className: string; someProp: string, anotherProp: Element }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SlotsProps`

Then I tried:

```
export interface ExampleProps extends PropsWithChildren<{}> {
  someProp: string,
  anotherProp: React.ReactNode
}
```

But this complains, `Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SlotsProps'`, since apparently all that PropsWithChildren contains is children.

So I also tried replacing `PropsWithChildren` with `ComponentProps` and `ElementType` but this didn't help either.

Does React not maintain a list of standard props that apply to all elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should indeed use the `extends`:

```
export interface ExampleProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
    someProp: string;
}

export default function Example({ someProp, ...restProps }: ExampleProps) {
    return <div {...restProps} />;
}
```

Depending on your IDE, you can actually click [or hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1pkX.png) the element you want and read it's type.

Answer (score 1):

Comming back to this question a year and a half later after having used juliomrc's answer in my code, I have some new insights I would like to share:

Don't do this! It's not a good idea.

HTML elements have a lot of props. Adding them to your reusable component hurts discoverability. Someone who is using autocomplete on your component will have to wade through a hundred generic props that are never used by anyone in order to find the few that are specific to your component.

In practice you almost always only need the following:

```
interface ElementProps {
  id?: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  style?: CSSProperties;
}
```

Furthermore, you might end up with conflicting prop definitions especialy with event handlers. Personally I prefer the following signature for `onChange`:

```
onChange: (value: T, event: ChangeEvent) => any
```

This allows you to just pass the setter for a react state. But this will clash with the one you get from HTMLAttributes.

But even if you are willing to use HTMLAttributes event handlers the target for your event handler might be different than the element to which you pass the rest of the props. So you will have exclude it from the HTMLAttributes and redefine it.

It's just not worth it, in my opinion. Better to hint at the props you actually use.

If you really do want to be able to pass arbitrary props to a particular HTML element you can always make a specific prop for that:

```
interface ElementProps {
  id?: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  style?: CSSProperties;
  containerProps?: HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>,
}

export function Element({children, containerProps, ...props}: ElementProps) {
  // ...

  return (
    <div {...{...props, ...containerProps}}>
      {/* ... */}
      { children }
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export function TypographyH1({
  children,
  ...props
}: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>) {
```

use this method for specific element types
you can change specific element types into this

```
<div/> = <HTMLDivElement>
<a/> = <HTMLAnchorElement>
<span /> = <HTMLSpanElement/>
<input /> = <HTMLInputElement/>
```